# CentOS - Automatically run fsck on boot into recovery

Tags: centos5, fsck

I'm automating a process to upgrade my ext3 filesystem to ext4. Following the instructions from [here](http://www.fractalizer.ru/frpost_472/centos-migrating-root-and-any-other-filesystem-from-ext3-to-ext4/comment-page-1/) I'm able to successfully migrate my filesystem. I've scripted the vast majority of the work, and it's working pretty nicely.

However, the final step in the migration is running `fsck` on the unmounted partition. The issue is that I'm trying to migrate the root partition, which can't be unmounted during normal operations. So to run `fsck`, I need to boot into recovery mode, enter the root password, and run `fsck` that way.

Is it possible to configure CentOS to automatically run `fsck` on boot into recovery?

Comment: I just read the instructions you referenced - this looks awful. I think that upgrade procedure is weird - there has to be a better way to do it. A simple "needs check" will not work according to the procedure...

Comment: Agreed, those instructions are forked, why isn't that guy just doing an rsync from one partition to the other. The part about creating a new initrd might be viable though, since the original might not include the ext4 driver.

Comment: @Tim I'm attempting to upgrade the root partition, as opposed to creating a new one. Is there an easier way to get an ext4 partition?

Comment: Not that I know of, but I certainly feel more comfortable with a clean partition opposed to an upgraded one.

Comment: @Tim right. Especially if I were starting off a soft-raid-device - like in the instructions. I would break the mirror into two degraded mirrors, make a clean ext4, `rsync -aHS`, modify grub, boot it and reattach the other side.

Comment: @Nils What is a soft-raid device? One thing to keep in mind here is that I'm on a Rackspace cloud server, and I have no control over disk configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Why running an automatic `fsck` on system start won't work? `fsck -pvfDC0` isn't doing anything special, just optimising the directories (the -D option) -- that's only part of ext4 file system. Extents is what makes it ext4. Just make it do fsck and reboot:

```
touch /forcefsck
shutdown -r now
```

Ext4 driver can read ext2, ext3 **and** ext4 file system, it's all the same for it. So yes, making sure your system is can boot from ext4 *is* important, having pure ext4 fs *isn't*.

That being said, I'd still go for creating a new partition as ext4 and copying data over -- it will be faster (access to partition, not the migration) and safer.